# ActionListener method of a CommandButton inside Datatable (within TabView) don't work

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, commandbutton

I've a CommandButton component inside Datatable, which is within a TabView component. ActionListener method of CommandButton component don't work. Never is fired.

This is my XHTML page:

```
<p:dialog id="dlgView" widgetVar="wvDlgView"
    modal="true" closable="true" resizable="false">
    <p:outputPanel id="opViewUser">
    <h:form>
        <p:tabView id="tabViewUser">
            <p:tab title="DATOS PERSONALES">
                <p:dataTable id="dtUsuarios" rows="5" paginator="true"
                    selectionMode="single" selection="#{personController.system}">
                    ....
                    <p:column>

                        <p:commandButton value="Bloquear"  actionListener="#{personController.block}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:tab>
        <p:tabView>
    </h:form>
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:dialog>
```

Thanks in advance :)

PD: PF 3.5, JSF (Mojarra) 2.1.3, Tomcat: 6.0.10

Comment: Hard to say without bean code, but maybe a bad bean scope?

Comment: Bean scope is @ViewScoped. I don't put bean code because error us that method never is fired. If there was a sintaxis error would show error message but this don't happen. Therefore I think that it's primefaces issue

Comment: Do you have a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that reproduce the error? Shortened example of your current view and bean.

Comment: It's more likely that you made a mistake in your code. As the code posted so far looks okay and you didn't post an SSCCE and the question is therefore unanswerable, here's just a link with all possible causes so that you can exclude the one and other yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183

Comment: Thanks @BalusC !. Option 3 was my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for not posting completely code and answer later. At any rate I think already it isn't necessary because I solved my problem. Explain in more detail the problem:

I had a structure similar to this on tab component:

```
<p:tab>
<h:form id="formTab" prependId="false">
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <p:outputLabel value="Sistema " for="sltSystem"/>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="sltSistema" required="true"
            value="#{personController.idSistema}" >
            <f:selectItems value="#{personController.listSistemas" 
                var="s" itemLabel="#{s.valor}" itemValue="#{s.id}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>

        <p:outputLabel value="Rol " for="sltRol"/>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="sltRol" required="true" 
            value="#{personController.idRol}" >
            <f:selectItems value="#{personController.listRoles}" 
                var="r" itemLabel="#{r.valor}" itemValue="#{r.id}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGrid>


    <p:dataTable id="dtUsersSystems" rows="5" paginator="true"
        value="#{personController.userSystems}" var="s" rowKey="#{s.id}" >

        <p:column headerText="SISTEMA">
            <h:outputText value="#{s.sistema}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="ROL">
            <h:outputText value="#{s.rol}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="ESTADO">
            <h:outputText value="#{s.estado}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column>

            <p:commandButton value="Bloquear" icon="ui-icon-cancel" actionListener="#{personController.blocked}"></p:commandButton>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
<h:form>
</p:tab>
```

As you can see **sltSystem** and **sltRol** components have **`required`** attribute in **`true`**. For that when I clicked on button "Bloquear" its ActionListener method not was invoked because after I should select a value on sltSystem and sltRol components.

Therefore new page structure is this:

```
<p:tab>
<h:form id="formSelect" prependId="false">
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <p:outputLabel value="Sistema " for="sltSystem"/>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="sltSistema" required="true"
            value="#{personController.idSistema}" >
            <f:selectItems value="#{personController.listSistemas" 
                var="s" itemLabel="#{s.valor}" itemValue="#{s.id}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>

        <p:outputLabel value="Rol " for="sltRol"/>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="sltRol" required="true" 
            value="#{personController.idRol}" >
            <f:selectItems value="#{personController.listRoles}" 
                var="r" itemLabel="#{r.valor}" itemValue="#{r.id}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
<h:form id="formDataTable" prependId="false">
    <p:dataTable id="dtUsersSystems" rows="5" paginator="true"
        value="#{personController.userSystems}" var="s" rowKey="#{s.id}" >

        <p:column headerText="SISTEMA">
            <h:outputText value="#{s.sistema}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="ROL">
            <h:outputText value="#{s.rol}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="ESTADO">
            <p:graphicImage value="#{s.estado}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column>

            <p:commandButton value="Bloquear" icon="ui-icon-cancel" actionListener="#{personController.blocked}"></p:commandButton>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
<h:form>
</p:tab>
```

A form for selectonemenu components and other form for datatable component.

Thanks to all :)